# MongoDB recovery database from Compass

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, recovery, mongodb-compass

I was working on a new project. There was a lot of data that I needed to add locally. I used mongoose and nodejs for this. But windows 11 where the project is installed does not open now. Fortunately, I have ubuntu on my computer and I can access windows files.

My question is that; There is a data folder in the mongoDB directory in the program files. Is there any chance I can recover my old data from here?

Comment: What's not opening - the app, the shell connection to the database, the database itself isn't running, something else? What's the error message?

Comment: There is no error. I'm using also mongodb in ubuntu. But i want to recovery my old database from windows to ubuntu. Unfortunately windows not opening but i can access files. I want to know how can i get databese files from the windos